# Newbie Ruby question - project basic calculator

Tags: ruby, calculator

I just started to learn ruby and I have a small project I'm working on. I'm making a simple **two** number calculator. What I want to do is get the user to input two numbers and then ask them if they would like to add/subtract/multiply them. My problem is, I want a message to fire if the user doesn't type in add/subtract/multiply. Say the user types **Ad** instead of **Add**, I want the computer to say "I don't understand!" I'm not sure how to execute this.

Here is my code so far.

```
puts "Welcome to math.rb!"
puts "Enter a number!"
     user = gets.to_i
puts "Enter another number!"
    user2 = gets.to_i
puts "What would you like to do with your number? You can add, subtract, or multiply!"

math = gets.chomp.downcase 
if math == "add"
    puts user + user2
end 
if math == "subtract"
    puts user - user2
end
if math == "multiply"
    puts user * user2
end
if math != ["add", "subtract", "multiply"]
    puts "I don't understand"
end
```

Comment: So if you think about what you've written it doesn't really make sense, right?  Your case occurs if a string *is not equal to* an array of strings, which is of course always true.  Whether you're new to programming or an old pro, researching for examples and documentation is something you'll do often.  Try googling "how do I check if an array includes an item in ruby"; you'll find many relevant answers.

Comment: Thank you! I for sure need to do more learning. I wasn't sure how to search for what I was looking for and now I got some reading to do too!

Comment: No problem, just to be clear if what I said seemed harsh it wasn't intended that way.  Learning how to identify your problem/task and then researching best/alternative practices on how to solve it is one of the foundational skills of the job.  Welcome to programming :-)

Comment: No, no, I completely understand. I'm still figuring this all out and I totally get pushing someone to do the research. I just need to develop the vocabulary to look in the right direction. I'm for sure not there yet on that aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use if statement with `elsif` and `else`.

```
math = gets.chomp.downcase 
if math == "add"
    puts user + user2
elsif math == "subtract"
    puts user - user2
elsif math == "multiply"
    puts user * user2
else
    puts "I don't understand"
end
```

`case` is also nice for this usecase.

```
math = gets.chomp.downcase 
case math
when "add"
    puts user + user2
when "subtract"
    puts user - user2
when "multiply"
    puts user * user2
else
    puts "I don't understand"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the code further and use a [hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) to store allowed operations, and [`eval`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval) to evaluate the resulting string as an arithmetic expression. Even though `eval` is not safe in many cases, here we strictly control its input, making it much safer.

Note that to control the input, I keep the `to_i` conversion (without it, the user can enter arbitrary strings, which would be unsafe to be directly `eval`-ed). The hash further controls the input by converting the string operators to hash values, which we completely control.

```
puts 'Welcome to math.rb!'
puts 'Enter a number!'
x = gets.to_i
puts 'Enter another number!'
y = gets.to_i
puts 'What would you like to do with your number? You can add, subtract, or multiply!'

op_str = gets.chomp.downcase

op_str_to_math = { 'add' => '+', 'subtract' => '-', 'multiply' => '*' }

if op_str_to_math.key? op_str
  puts eval "#{x} #{op_str_to_math[op_str]} #{y}"
else
  puts "I don't understand"
end
```

---

`op_str_to_math = { ... }` defines a hash with key `=>` value pairs. The elements of the hash can be accessed like so:

```
puts op_str_to_math['add'] # prints: +
puts op_str_to_math['subtract'] # prints: -
```

We check if the operator is allowed by looking up the user input (`op_str`) among the hash keys: `if op_str_to_math.key? op_str` .

`eval "..."` evaluates the string. Because the string is double-quoted, the values in #{...} are interpolated. So if the user entered, for example, `2`, `3`, `add`, the string gets interpolated to `2 + 3`, which is `5`.

Finally, I replaced where appropriate all double quotes with single quotes, per Ruby coding conventions.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I will say, this is well outside my knowledge base. I'm three sessions in on coding course a buddy from work is running. I'm still trying to grasp arrays and loops and all the bare basics. This is kind of flying over my head right now. I've been reading about loops all evening trying to figure out how to loop the add/subtract/multiply section of my code until the user inputs add or subtract or multiply. I might just need to walk away from it for a bit.

Comment: Consider instead `op = { 'add' => :+, 'subtract' => :-, 'multiply' => :* }; op_str = 'add'; x = 2; y = 5;  x.public_send(op[op_str], y) #=> 7; op_str = 'multiply'; x.public_send(op[op_str], y) #=> 10`. One can alternatively write `op = { 'add' => '+', 'subtract' => '-', 'multiply' => '*' }`. One must be cautious when using `eval`because of potential security problems.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think your comment deserves be a separate (and accepted, IMO) answer. It is brief, easy to maintain, and safe. If you make it into an answer, please ping me, and I will then delete my (less safe, eval-based) answer.

Comment: I offer comments as I would if I were reviewing a draft of a book or article. The writer is free to use them however they like. I expect no recognition but if any is given I would prefer it be a general thank-you in a comment, so as to not pollute the answer. I have often received helpful comments to my answers, which I have incorportated in my answers, removing anything I had previously written that no longer made the grade. My objective is simply to be as helpful as I can to the asker and other readers.